# jquery autocomplete default

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

is there any way how to add default option to autocomplete plugin, which will be shown in all cases, even when the word doesn't match the JSON results?

This is what I'm trying to do:

Whenever you write anything to search input you should get "hledat vyraz {value}" as the first suggested option - means perform classic search, since we might have a lot of articles about Adriana Lima and autocomplete shows only some. So I've added this option to JSON.

It works correctly until I' write "adriana ", the space after the keyword cause that autocomplete won't show "hledat vyraz adriana".

Is there any way how to force to add the default first option, which will be shown all the time?

Live example on http://www.mdls.cz.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `source` function that always includes the item you want on top:

```
var arrayOfItems = [{title:"Something about Adriana"},
    {title:"Something about Adriana 2"},{title:"Something about Adriana 3"},
    {title:"Something else"}];

$("#input").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var itemsMatched = [];
        itemsMatched.push({value: "Classic search for '" + request.term}+"'")

        $.each(arrayOfItems, function(i, item) {
            if(item.title.indexOf(request.term)>=0)
                itemsMatched.push({value: item.title});
        });

        response(itemsMatched);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pvp7x8ju/1/